# Output gzipped result as a stream

Tags: php, gzip

I have a simple PHP script that output a sitemap from a list of URLs.

The sitemap is generated on the fly, so far I can output XML directly and it works, but I think compressed XML is better.

```
header ('Content-Type: application/xml');

echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>', "\n";
echo '<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">', "\n";

$handle = gzopen($file, 'r');
while (!gzeof($handle))
{
    $buffer = trim(gzgets($handle, 4096));
    echo "\t", '<url><changefreq>weekly</changefreq><priority>0.5</priority><loc><![CDATA[http://', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_HOST'], '/', $buffer, ']]></loc></url>', "\n";
}
gzclose($handle);

echo '</urlset>';
```

To generate `sitemap-1.xml.gz` on the fly I can populate the XML in memory then gzip it and output the result, but it would cost a lot of server memories, e.g

```
echo gzcompress(create_sitemap());
```

A better solution would be writing gzip output block by block, as a stream.

Is it even possible?

Comment: @PaulCrovella the xml is generated on the fly, will update question

Comment: @PaulCrovella attached source code